# Delete Empty or null element in a array collection

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I would like to remove from my database any empty text field on my controller.

Here is my test that I've done without any issues:

```
             $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $listScrap = $em->getRepository('VPScraplistBundle:Scraplist')->find($id);

       ...      


            $form = $this->createForm(new \VP\ScraplistBundle\Form\ScraplistType(), $listScrap);


            if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {




              foreach ($listScrap->gethistoriques() as $historique) {
                   if  ($historique->gethistorique()->isEmpty()) {

                     $listScrap->removeCategory($historique);

                  }
                }

 $em->flush();
              $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Index bien modifiée.');

...
```

I've also tested :

```
   if  ($historique->gethistorique()->isEmpty()) {

                 $listScrap->removeCategory($historique);       

              }
```

And:

```
  if($historique->gethistorique()== ""){

                 $listScrap->removeCategory($historique);       

              }
```

Without any success, sorry about my English and thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You need to persist `$list` before flush him

`$em->persit($listScrap);`

Answer (score 0):

If method `$historique->gethistorique()` returns string you can not call `isEmpty()` from it. I think there is no need to persist `$listScrap` before `flush()`, because it's changes are already tracked by doctrine and will be saved upon flushing.
I think you should find out what exactly returns your method `$historique->gethistorique()` and if it is a string then checking whether string is empty must be enough.